# How to get items between two date with C3 from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

we use mongo db in our c# project. i want to select items between two date but mongo's datetime format is a little bit different.

how can i change the datetime formats ?

for example i want to run this query

```
startDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

assetQuery = assetQuery.Where(x => x.OnlineDate > startDateTime && x.OnlineDate != null);
```

but it doesn't work because of mongoDB date format.

how can we do this ?

Comment: Do you get an exception? I've done this plenty of times. If you remove the x.OnlineDate != null part do you get data?

Comment: I don't think you need the "x.OnlineDate != null" part.  If the OnlineDate is null the first part won't match.